# Energy conservation in motional emf

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, potential, electromagnetic-induction

If a rod enters a region of uniform electric field, a potential difference arises between the ends of the rod. The work required to create this potential difference comes from  the magnetic field. If the work done by the magnetic field increases the potential energy of the rod then would the kinetic energy possesed by the rod decrease?

Comment: The work done to create potential difference or drive current through the rod comes from kinetic energy of the rod (or the work of external force that pushes the rod against the magnetic force). Static magnetic field is the cause of magnetic force and motional EMF, but it does not lose any energy.

Answer (score 0):

The electric potential energy due to the separation of charges along the rod comes either from the work done by an external force acting on the rod to keep the rod moving at constant velocity or from a decrease in the kinetic energy of the rod as negative work is done on the rod by the force on the rod due to the interaction of the moving charges whilst setting up the potential difference and the magnetic field.

Comment: but the rod can be considered an open circuit right? will the current still flow

Comment: A current (movement of charges) will flow during the phase when a potential difference is created across the rod. After that phase no current will flow and no work needs to be done for the rod to move at constant velocity.

Comment: @AdityaAhuja Current will flow until there is charge separation and stop when $E+vXB$ = 0, where E is the electrostatic field due to charge separation.